# Remove specific nodes from XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I am trying to do something simple in c#.
I have an `XMLNode` `xNode` with the following

```
<TxnFrameworkImport>
  <RefreshData>False</RefreshData> 
  <Initializing>False</Initializing> 
  <CompanyID>1902</CompanyID> 
  <FolderID>-1</FolderID> 
  <SearchId>-1</SearchId> 
  <Remote>False</Remote> 
  <Parameters>
     <Parameter Type="Transactions" Name="TransactionKey">
       <Value Type="A" Name="584">7576</Value> 
       <Value Type="A" Name="123">66345</Value> 
       <Value Type="A" Name="4214">66346</Value> 
     </Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</TxnFrameworkImport>
```

I would like to remove the nodes that have the Values of `66345` and `66346`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another sample with XPath condition `or`.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Value[.=66345] | //Value[.=66346]"))
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using the **XDocument** system for XML is preferred over **XmlDocument**, here is one way to do it using the **XmlNode** object you asked about.

```
// "//Parameter/Value" is an XPath selector that finds any Parameter Node and selects the child Value nodes of it.
foreach (XmlNode valueNode in doc.SelectNodes("//Parameter/Value"))
{
    if (valueNode.InnerText == "66345" || valueNode.InnerText == "66346")
    {
        valueNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(valueNode);
    }
}
```

You can read more about XPath [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)